# Rspec: Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:user)).to be_persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a simple controller Rspec test. I'm testing the User controller create action.

But i receive this error

```
$ rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
.....F

Failures:

  1) UsersController POST #create user created
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:user)).to be_persisted
       expected `#<User id: nil, username: "username27", email: "user27@factory.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil, remember_digest: nil, admin: false, activation_digest: nil, activated: false, activated_at: nil, reset_digest: nil, >: nil, reset_sent_at: nil, avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil, description: nil, header_image_file_name: nil, header_image_content_type: nil, header_image_file_size: nil, header_image_updated_at: nil>.persisted?` to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.49926 seconds (files took 2.6 seconds to load)
```

Here is the test

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  let!(:admin) { create(:user, password: "Password123", admin: true) }
  let!(:user) { create(:user, password: "Password456", admin: false) }

  let!(:users) do
    [admin, user] + 3.times.map { create(:user) }
  end

  let!(:user_params) { user.attributes }

  describe "POST #create" do
    before do
      post :create, user: user_params
    end

    it "user created" do
      expect(assigns(:user)).to be_persisted
    end
  end
end
```

**When i put a binding.pry at the create action. Then run User.new(user_params).valid? = false**

```
$ rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
.....
From: /Users/joseph/Documents/Safsy/Website/Safsy/Safsy/app/controllers/users_controller.rb @ line 26 UsersController#create:

    24: def create
    25:   @user = User.new(user_params)
 => 26:   binding.pry
    27:   if @user.save
    28:     @user.send_activation_email
    29:     flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
    30:     redirect_to root_url
    31:   else
    32:     render 'new'
    33:   end
    34: end

[1] pry(#<UsersController>)> User.new(user_params)
=> #<User:0x007fa749fc1b18
 id: nil,
 username: "username27",
 email: "user27@factory.com",
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 password_digest: nil,
 remember_digest: nil,
 admin: false,
 activation_digest: nil,
 activated: false,
 activated_at: nil,
 reset_digest: nil,
 >: nil,
 reset_sent_at: nil,
 avatar_file_name: nil,
 avatar_content_type: nil,
 avatar_file_size: nil,
 avatar_updated_at: nil,
 description: "Vel aperiam et dolorem aliquid est perspiciatis.",
 header_image_file_name: nil,
 header_image_content_type: nil,
 header_image_file_size: nil,
 header_image_updated_at: nil>
```

**Any clues how to fix it? Its like only some of my attributes for the user_params in my tests are getting passed too the create action**

```
Here are is a binding.pry at the Test

    50:   end
    51:
    52:   describe "POST #create" do
    53:     before do
    54:       post :create, user: user_params
 => 55:       binding.pry
    56:     end
    57:
    58:     it "user created" do
    59:       expect(assigns(:user)).to be_persisted
    60:     end

[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::POSTCreate>)> user_params
=> {"id"=>2,
 "username"=>"username27",
 "email"=>"user27@factory.com",
 "created_at"=>Wed, 07 Oct 2015 12:24:01 UTC +00:00,
 "updated_at"=>Wed, 07 Oct 2015 12:24:01 UTC +00:00,
 "password_digest"=>"$2a$04$Y627EwOml9cix7NdPITnpem0nZV8fta.JNyuezRsLNF2ucKfdC3GC",
 "remember_digest"=>nil,
 "admin"=>false,
 "activation_digest"=>"$2a$04$LHRBD82Lm0bj20nrwHDVveVlUa7zWq0WYIlmTMivT1h9UIcjwv9FO",
 "activated"=>true,
 "activated_at"=>nil,
 "reset_digest"=>nil,
 ">"=>nil,
 "reset_sent_at"=>nil,
 "avatar_file_name"=>nil,
 "avatar_content_type"=>nil,
 "avatar_file_size"=>nil,
 "avatar_updated_at"=>nil,
 "description"=>"Nihil eligendi ab debitis iure.",
 "header_image_file_name"=>nil,
 "header_image_content_type"=>nil,
 "header_image_file_size"=>nil,
 "header_image_updated_at"=>nil}
```

**Look at the user_params here in the test then look at them in the create action. They're the same. Just some attributes like password and password confirmation aren't being passed.**

Comment: Have you checked if the user where you get the user_params from has been persisted? Do you white-list parameters in your controller? Aren't you white-listing only email, username, description, and password?

Comment: In you model or your DB, do you check for :password presence? If so it will fail without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your specs like below and it should work -

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  let!(:admin) { create(:user, password: "Password123", admin: true) }
  let!(:user) { create(:user, password: "Password456", admin: false) }

  let!(:users) do
    [admin, user] + 3.times.map { create(:user) }
  end

  let!(:user_params) { user.dup.attributes }

  describe "POST #create" do
    it "user created" do
      valid_user_params = { username: "username#{rand(1000)}", 
       email: "user#{rand(1000)}@factory.com",
       password: "Password123",
       password_confirmation: "Password123",
       admin: false,
       description: "Nihil eligendi ab debitis iure." }
      post :create, user: valid_user_params
      expect(assigns(:user)).to be_persisted
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Read the last bold text on the description

Comment: `user_params` should be different there must be validation for user password and password confirmation and uniqueness for username

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you. I still don't know why my way didn't work. user_params in my Spec has the same attributes. It just wansn't getting passed. I will refractor what you have made. But it's good fix for now. Thank you so much!!!